# Ajax update & form input select field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, x-editable

I have the follow ajax code (using jquery and x-editable plugin) for updating a select field.

```
            <a href="#" id="days" data-pk="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-url="post.php" data-title="days" data-type="select" class="editable editable-click">
            <?php
                if (!empty($days)) { echo $days;
                } else { echo "Please Select";
                }
                ?>
            </a>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $('#days').editable({
                        source : [{
                            value : '',
                            text : 'Please select'
                        }, {
                            value : '1',
                            text : '1 day'
                        }, {
                            value : '30',
                            text : '1 month'
                        }, {
                            value : '360',
                            text : '1 year'
                        }]
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

After field is updated, it displays the select text '1 day', '1 month' or '1 year' as the way I want.

But after a page refresh, it displays the select value, as '1', '30' or '360'.

What I need to do display the text from select?

Thank you!!!

Comment: are you trying to remember what the user picked, the next time the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

To remember and display the option user selects you need to store it in session variable in ajax call.

Sample high level example:

```
$.ajax{(
  url:../store.php,
  data: optionselected:selected,
  method:post
});
```

In `store.php` set it to a session variable and use this for display while user reloads page.